# Python NameError: Name not defined (CloudFlare DDNS Script)

Tags: python, windows, nameerror, cloudflare

So I have an account with CloudFlare and I'm trying to use [this Python Script](https://github.com/ttsda/CfDDNS) to update my DNS to my new IP address if it ever changes

I have installed Python for Windows, and also installed the dependency 'Requests' via pip.

When trying to run the script I'm getting this error:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\CFDDNS\CfDDNS-master>python cfddns.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cfddns.py", line 96, in <module>
    main()
  File "cfddns.py", line 60, in main
  execfile(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'config.py'), config)
NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined
```

I've never used Python before so I'm a bit out of my depth, I think it's trying to get an Env Variable from my PC, but isn't finding it? - But I'm not sure, and I wouldn't know what to add to fix this.

I'm trying to run this on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard, for now just manually. I will work out automation later on when the script works.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`execfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile) is a builtin function in Python2, but has been removed in Python 3,  To run this program you probably need the [correct python version.](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-279/)

Comment: Yep, you were correct!

I thought it might of been that, so I installed Python2 (alongside Python3) - I had to uninstall both and re-install Python2.

Thanks for the help!